In Oracle, does a DDL script need commit statements when run with sqlplus?
DDL scripts do not need COMMIT statements as per the docs.
If I run these statements in SQL Developer, no commit is required:
CREATE TABLE dummy_table(ID NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE SEQUENCE dummy_seq START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NOCACHE;

When I run with sqlplus, log says :
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Jul 3 11:28:54 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0
 
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 
Last Successful login time: Wed Jul 03 2024 11:28:53 +02:00
 
Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.23.0.0.0
 
 
Table created.
 
 
Sequence created.
 
SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.23.0.0.0

But when I check if the table and sequence were created, I can see that they were not created.
After adding COMMIT at the end of the script, still neither of them were created.
Only after adding COMMIT after each statement, both the table and the sequence were created.
My sqlplus command:
sqlplus  USER/"PASSWORD"@DATABASE @ /path/to/script.sql


DDL doesn't require COMMIT. SQL Plus reported that both table and sequence were created. Please, post the whole SQL Plus session which shows everything you did - how you connected, ran the script, checked whether objects exist.

@Sybuser - "But when I check if the table and sequence were created, I can see that they were not created." - show us exactly how you're doing this please

I do a select on the table, it says : "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"

please show us, show us where you login and run that query

There's a sh script which executes SQL scripts with sqlplus in a loop. I have to do a CTRL+D after each script to exit each sqlplus session (any idea how to avoid that?). It appears that when my SQL script is   executed alone, I don't have the issue.

No.
DDL causes everything in your session to be implicitly committed.
From the Docs:

Oracle Database issues an implicit COMMIT under the following
circumstances:
Before any syntactically valid data definition language (DDL)
statement, even if the statement results in an error
After any data definition language (DDL) statement that completes
without an error

This is true for any client side application issuing the work, INCLUDING  but not limited to, SQLPlus.
If you don't see your table and sequence when you 'went back in' to 'check it' - you either connected to the wrong database or you were looking in the wrong schema.

Colleagues gaslighting me and urging me to put additional commits where it makes no sense and by coincidence of circumstances it happens to work. I still try to figure out how.

Share your script, then we can teach you.
